# extract array that is inside and array of objects

Tags: javascript

```
var objs = [
  {labels: ["label1", "label2"]}, 
  {labels: ["label1", "label3"]},
  {labels: ["label2", "label4"]} 
]
```

i am trying to extract this ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"]

```
labels = this.get('objs').map(function(obj) {
           return obj.labels.map(function(label) {
             return label;
           });
         });
console.log(labels);
```

But the above code printed [["label1", "label2"], ["label1", "label3"], ["label2", "label4"]]

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you could map your `objs` array to get just the `labels` array, then remove dupe entries with `Set`.

```js
const objs = [
  {labels: ["label1", "label2"]}, 
  {labels: ["label1", "label3"]},
  {labels: ["label2", "label4"]},
];

const r = [...new Set([].concat(...objs.map(({ labels }) => labels)))];

console.log(r);
```

ES5:

```js
const objs = [
  {labels: ["label1", "label2"]}, 
  {labels: ["label1", "label3"]},
  {labels: ["label2", "label4"]},
];

const r = [...new Set([].concat(...objs.map(function(v) {
  return v.labels;
})))];

console.log(r);
```

Comment: could you provide this in es5?

Comment: @LokeshCherukuri Yeah, sure. I think that destructuring inside argument declaration might caused some compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using underscore

```
labels = _.union(this.get('objs').map(function(obj) {
    return obj.labels.map(function(label) {
        return label;
    })
}))
console.log(labels);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread element and `Set`

```
let res = [];

objs.forEach(({labels}) => res = [...res, ...labels]);

res = [...new Set(res)];
```

or `.filter()` and `.includes()`

```
var res = [];

objs.forEach(({labels}) => 
  res = [...res, ...labels.filter(prop => !res.includes(prop))]);
```